# Bottom up thinking - what is it?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, neuroscience, evolutionary-psychology, unconscious

Mlodinow has [book](http://leonardmlodinow.com/leonard-mlodiinow-books/elastic/) Elastic thinking, which sounds interesting and where he mentions bottom up processes/thinking; which he equates with elastic thinking.

I have watched numerous videos about it, and even read some sample chapters of the book - but to my surprise, it is still unclear to me what exactly he means by **bottom up thinking**?

One unclear quote from the book is:

> Elastic thought is where your new ideas come from. Imaginative, original, and non-linear, it is “bottom-up” thinking, in which insights percolate into the mind, seemingly from nowhere.

Another unclear quote:

> Elastic thinking is about stretching your mind and using ‘bottom up’ processing in the brain rather than the top down executive functions that drive analytical thinking

Can someone please bring **some simple and concrete examples from daily life**, of what is bottom up thinking?

ps. His book is based on research and says it is known term in science community, this elastic thinking/bottom up thinking, and hence my hope people here may know what is it.

Answer (score 2):

[Hutchinson, B. (2002)](https://books.google.co.uk/books?hl=en&lr=&id=xlbdBwAAQBAJ&oi=fnd&pg=PA445&dq=info:Ij26NE3sflEJ:scholar.google.com/&ots=xX1Xxu8yS2&sig=UmmHWYeNPQByN_Lpm9I8_aFOhqI#v=onepage&q&f=false), an article in the book *Synergy Matters* by Adrian M. Castell may help in understanding what is meant by *bottom up thinking* and the opposite, *top down thinking*.

> [T]he  term  ‘top  down’  is  used to  describe an  approach  to  problem solving  where  the  problem  space  is  defined  first.  The  worldviews  of  the  participants are used  to  conceptualise  the  desired  state  of  the  proposed system.  Once  this  is achieved,  the  system  is  developed  within  this  boundary.  The  components,  or subsystems  are  derived  within  the  context  of  the  predefined  desired state. The  term  ‘bottom  up’  is  used  to  describe  an  approach  where  no  assumptions  are  made about the  boundary  of  the  problem  space.  The  behaviour  of  component  parts  are rationally  observed  to  determine  the  properties they  have.  Management  decisions, or system designs  are  then  based  on  the  observed  behaviour  of  components.

An example given in the conclusions is:

> [I]nvestigating a system failure in bottom up mode would look for causes at the element level, or more precisely, at their interactions. The top down mode would tend to look at the overall system, and would put ‘blame’ on the system itself and how it functions, rather than emergent properties of system element interactions.

Think of it like a brick building.  You need to build it from the bottom up, with each brick being correctly placed to form the correct shape etc.  If the bricks are placed differently, you may get a different building, or maybe you will get the same building but badly constructed.

Take the following as a more detailed example comparison...

There is a team of researchers working on a task and each member inputs their findings into a computer system which analyses the results and comes up with a conclusion.

The program relies on accurate information from each team member entry but there was a slight error in a couple of entries producing an incorrect conclusion by the system.

A top down thinker would blame the computer system analysing the results.  A bottom up thinker would analyse what the system was analysing and how, leading to them finding the real cause.

### References

Hutchinson, B. (2002). Bottom up thinking. In *Synergy Matters* (pp. 445-450). Springer, Boston, MA. doi: [10.1007/0-306-47467-0_75](https://doi.org/10.1007/0-306-47467-0_75)
Preview available in [Google Books](https://books.google.co.uk/books?hl=en&lr=&id=xlbdBwAAQBAJ&oi=fnd&pg=PA445&dq=info:Ij26NE3sflEJ:scholar.google.com/&ots=xX1Xxu8yS2&sig=UmmHWYeNPQByN_Lpm9I8_aFOhqI#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Comment: better than my quotes, but still bit vague; more (concrete) examples would be welcome.

Comment: just a note: mladinows book is on research in psychology, whereas your link on research in management science. Not saying they aren't related, just made a note.